# Triangulate this identification space

Tags: general-topology, triangulation

$Z$ is an identification space of the unit square $Q=\{(x, y) | 0 \leq x, y \leq 1\}$ with the following identifications:

$(0, y)$~$(1, y)$

$(x, 0)$~$(x+ \frac{1}{2}, 0) $

$(x, 1) $~ $(x + \frac{1}{2}, 1)  $

I drew the following net:

[image: net]

But I am unsure how to construct a triangulation. Could you help me please?

Comment: By triangulation you mean a simplicial complex, right?

Comment: @StefanHamcke yes

Comment: You could start by triangulating the image of the boundary of $Q$ in $Z$. Do you see what the minimal number of edges is for this subspace? Then think about which pairs of edges can be made the edges of a triangle by adding a third line into the picture. You might have to subdivide the edges further in order to make different triangles have different vertices.

Comment: would a a subdivision into 9 squares, which are each halved to give 18 triangles work?

Comment: If you mean $3\times 3$ squares, I don't think so. Remind that the first half of the upper edge is identified to the second half. So instead of three edges, you rather need to subdivide it into six edges. But a subdivision into $18$ squares does indeed work. I think $12$ squares is also enough.